# Using proxy with nginx for GeoServer on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxypass

I have succesfully intalled a GeoServer 2.11.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. with nginx. I've set up a proxy using nginx following this [guide](https://gist.github.com/thanhleviet/3040490), so now my configuration file for nginx looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        proxy_redirect off;
        location /geodata {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/;
        }
}
```

When I enter `localhost/geodata/` I reach the GeoServer frontpage. **So far so good.**

However,

- when I press a link, such as the login-button, I get the message:

`http://localhost/j_spring_security_check: /j_spring_security_check not found`

- Or when I go into `Demos -> WCS request builder` then I get the error:

`/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wcs.web.demo.WCSRequestBuilder;jsessionid=1i5x791bktwq9a2ug77vyax7n?4 not found`

In the latter, note how the address is `geoserver`, and *not* `geodata`. This tells me that somehow the `proxy_pass` isn't working for anything but the frontpage.

Is the `proxy_pass` not sufficient for this to work?

**EDIT** Here is the log of one succesful and one unsuccesful event

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017:08:48:22 +0200] "GET /geodata/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wcs.web.demo.WCSRequestBuilder;jsessionid=1i945lcowjlas113w2ru2mo5j HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://localhost/geodata/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.DemoPage;jsessionid=1i945lcowjlas113w2ru2mo5j" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"

127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017:08:48:22 +0200] "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wcs.web.demo.WCSRequestBuilder;jsessionid=1i945lcowjlas113w2ru2mo5j?3 HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "http://localhost/geodata/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.DemoPage;jsessionid=1i945lcowjlas113w2ru2mo5j" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

Comment: Do you see those messages on the page, or in a log? Your comment towards the end, the URL is supposed to be /geoserver/web, because that's the route on the application.

Comment: @JoeBrailsford I see this on the page itself, not in the log.

Comment: It seems like it's the application telling you the page is not found, but, it could always be nginx trying to consume the request. Can you browse to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web on the server, does everything work?

Comment: @JoeBrailsford Yes, there everything works fine.

Comment: Okay, so run `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` and repeat the login request, copy the output into your question.

Comment: @JoeBrailsford Thanks, I added the output of the log

Answer (score 1):

It'll be easier to diagnose once we get some logs, but for a starter, could you try:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /path/to/geoserver/directory;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location ^~ /geoserver/web/ { 
        rewrite ^/geoserver/web(/.*)$ /geodata$1 permanent;
    }

    location ^~ /j_spring_security_check {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver/;
    }

    location ^~ /geodata/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/;
    }


}
```

If you, on the server, navigate to http://localhost:8080/geoserver (not geoserver/web) - does it still work?

Comment: Yes, it works if I manually nagivate to http://localhsot:8080/geoserver. It is only when I use the address of the proxy that it doesn't

Comment: What's the path to geoserver/web on your system?

Comment: Could you try the above (now edited) config, and replace the root directive to match the path your files are in.

Comment: I tried changing the path to a few alternatives: `/usr/share/geoserver`, `/usr/share/geoserver/webapps`, `/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver` and `/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF` but none of them fixed the issue. I remembered to restart nginx after each try

Comment: Try the edited config.

Comment: Still a 404-error, I get the same behaviour and response. Could it be that a symbolic link has to be made to something on the server? Just a wild guess

Comment: Try my edit. Your problem is that subsequent requests are being sent to the wrong url, /geoserver/web rather than /geodata.

Comment: (just changed it slightly again, if that doesn't work, delete the new location block and uncomment the rewrite)

Comment: Thanks. I tried both versions, unfortunately they didn't do the trick. I think that simply some of the URLs in GeoServer refer to the wrong `/geoserver/web`.

Comment: Essentially, you need nginx to rewrite /geoserver/web to /geodata and pass any params, try my new edit. If that doesn't work, I'm at a loss, generally to debug this I'd be flicking to the logs and back a lot.

Comment: I think you have the right idea! But the current script doesn't append the params, so it just goes to `localhost/geodata/` when I press an url. But if we can append the params, I think we got it!

Comment: Updated, try again.

Comment: This inserts `geodata` so the url becomes `.../geodata/geoserver/web/...` - is there a way to delete the two entries after `geodata`, i.e. delete `geoserver/web/`?

Comment: Try that, just a guess.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! The login still gives me an error though, it points to `localhost/j_spring_security_check` which gives me a 404. But looking in the log, I can't see what the correct URL for the login is. Do you know how?

Comment: Could you do the request and post the output of your access.log?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017:11:25:20 +0200] "POST /j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "http://localhost/geodata/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"`

Comment: Is your to directive set to /usr/share/geoserver ?

Comment: Yes, it is set to `/usr/share/geoserver`

Comment: You could try the above, but I'd be surprised if it works. Have you tried the other answer by Tero? If mine doesn't work, try appending web/ to the /geoserver/ section of the new location.... Edit: I'm fairly certain Tero's answer will just work, and is exceedingly better.

Comment: I gave it a try, it didn't work unfortunately. I'll try Tero's suggestion, I just have to find out how to actually change the base URL in GeoServer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues here:

1. Your geoserver software has its base URL set to `/geoserver/web`, which means it it produces links beginning with that. You need to change the configuration of the software to change the base URL.
2. Your nginx configuration makes every request that begins with `/geodata` go to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/` URL on the backend. Therefore the rest of the URL is lost in the process. To fix this, you need to use the following configuration:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
       index index.html index.htm;
       proxy_redirect off;
       location ~ ^/geodata(.*)$ {
           include proxy_params;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web$1;
       }
   }
   ```

Here we capture the part appearing after `/geodata` to a variable, and then append the contents of the variable to the `proxy_pass` destination.

Comment: Thanks Tero. Do you know how I can change the base URL in GeoServer? I tried changing the `Proxy Base URL` to `http://localhost/geodata/`, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with the software.